# Prolog question, manipulate list of lists

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and have a question:

Suppose I have a list of lists; `[list1, list2, list3,..., list_n]`

If  `list_j` contains `list_i`, i.e. every variable in `list_i` occurs in `list_j`, then remove `list_j`.

For example, if the input is

```
[[a,b,c], [a,c], [a,d], [a,d,e]]
```

the output should be

```
[[a,c], [a,d]]
```

because `[a,b,c]` contains `[a,c]` and `[a,d,e]` contains `[a,d]`.

How to implement this in SWI-Prolog? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide at least what you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, SWI already has a predicate to check whether a list is "contained" (in terms of set-inclusion) in another list: `subset/2` (http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=subset/2).

Now you can use that to check whether or not to remove a specific list from all lists:

```
remove(Lists, List) :-
    member(List, Lists),
    member(Sublist, Lists),
    Sublist \= List,
    subset(Sublist, List).
```

Read as: `remove` `List` from `Lists` if it is a `member` of `Lists` and there is also another (confirmed by `\=`) `member` of `Lists` (call it `Sublist`), which is a `subset` of `List`.

```
?- remove([[a,b,c], [a,c], [a,d], [a,d,e]], L).
L = [a, b, c] ;
L = [a, d, e] ;
```

Now you can use that to answer your original question:

```
remaining(Lists, Remaining) :-
    bagof(List,
          ( 
              member(List, Lists),
              \+ remove(Lists, List)
          ),
          Remaining).
```

Let these lists be `Remaining` from `Lists` which are `member`s of the original list of `Lists` and are not (`\+`) to be `remove`d.

```
?- remaining([[a,b,c], [a,c], [a,d], [a,d,e]], Remaining).
Remaining = [[a, c], [a, d]].
```